# How to provide a simple data structure with Java system properties

Tags: java, xml

We have an xml-parser (implemented in Java) that parse xml documents as shown below.

Now we want to add functionality in the xml-parser, which lets users override values in the xml-file from the command line, i.e. system properties (-D property). There should be no need of preparing the xml-file in any way.

It should be possible to provide a -D property with a syntax something like this:

```
-Dxml.id0001=host:22.33.44.55,ports:6000;6001
```

XML-FILE:

```
<resources> 
    <resource id="id001">
        <property name="host">123.234.34.56</property>
        <property name="ports">7000;7001</property>
    </resource>
    <resource id="id002">
        <property name="host">987.876.765.54</property>
    </resource>
</resources>
```

Question:
What delimiter characters should be used in the -D property, to avoid putting constraint on the data in the xml document? For example in the above example 
    7000;7001
contains ";" in it's value, so can't use that as a delimiter. I want the xml data to be able to contain any data independent of the syntax of the -D property.

Would this be a better syntax:

```
-Dxml.id0001=<host>22.33.44.55<ports>6000;6001
```

as the "less/greater than" characters are not allowed in text values in XML.

Additionally:
Are there any existing parser libraries that can help with this? I searched but could not find one.

The syntax will become more advance in future,

```
-Dxml.*=<host>22.33.44.55<ports>6000;6001 // change host/port for any resource
-Dxml.*=<host<135.246.357.468>>22.33.44.55 // change host only for resources that has host=135.246.357.468
```

etc. etc.

Comment: Why not ask user to prepare his own xml file (same format as your xml) and provide the path to file as system property? If system property not provided, use default values. If file path provided, parse both files, pickup default values for properties not overridden by user.

Comment: IMO you're trying to cram too much into a single `-D`--any DSL that is basically XSL will end up being sad to use. I'd rather see something like Groovy/etc. or just a normal ETL engine and save yourself the trouble of trying to implement, and use, this.

Comment: The xml file(s) are relatively large (500-1000 elements). The xml-files are modified in a central place and the user don't have write access. So this is a way for user to temporarily change values for their session, not affecting others.

Comment: why -D rather than a normal command line argument?  with a command line argument you could pass in an xpath, for example (because you're not trying to force things into a valid system properties name)

Comment: We use the data in the xml file when running automated test cases, with TestNG, so we don't have access to the main() method.